# detect a change on a std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

i had a question about detecting a change on a std_logic_vector(4 downto 0).
Here is my code :

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
library work;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

Entity CHANGE_CUR_GRP is
port(
    MCLK    : in std_logic;
    RST_N   : in std_logic;
    CUR_GRP : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
    LOAD    : out std_logic
);

end entity;

Architecture RTL of CHANGE_CUR_GRP is

signal grp     : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
signal compare : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

  begin
    process(RST_N, MCLK)
      begin
        if(RST_N = '0') then
          LOAD <= '0';
        elsif(rising_edge(MCLK)) then
          grp <= CUR_GRP;
        end if;
    end process;

  LOAD <= '1' when compare = "00000" else '1';
  compare <= grp xor CUR_GRP;

end Architecture;
```

But when i run my simulation i got a 'X' whine means that the signal has multiple drivers and i don't know why.

Thank you

Comment: `LOAD` does have multiple drivers. It is driven by the process (in the reset branch, which drives it to `'0'`) and also in the one liner outside the process, that always drives it to `'1'`. Hence it will always be `'X'`.  You cannot assign it in both places.

Comment: OT: Do you really mean `LOAD <= '1' when ... else '1';`?

Comment: @Tricky Please write an actual answer. Please do not solidify the impression that questions could be answered in comments.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your responses. Even when i remove the "RST_N" i still have LOAD at 'X'

Comment: Yes tricky, i noticzed that, but as i said even if i remove  "RST_N" i still get the same result. Yes sorry, i did'nt see your responses

Comment: i changed the code (i can't put it because they're not accepting more answers from me)

Comment: To change the code - simply modify the original question.

Comment: Ill also note that the question body doesnt really match with the question title.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. You got *a 'X' Whine* (what does that mean?) on which signal? When? See [ask]. Contrary to busybee's assertion this question isn't useful to future readers as is and there will likely be duplicates found by search on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Note your question shows up among others with Stackoverflow search terms *[vhdl] multiple drivers 'X'*.

Answer (score 0):

`LOAD` does have multiple drivers. It is driven by the process (in the reset branch, which drives it to '0') and also in the one liner outside the process, that always drives it to '1'. Hence it will always be 'X'. You cannot assign it in both places.

To fix the problem, either remove the one liner assignment (which as @thebusybee already pointed out, looks like an error anyway) or remove the line `LOAD <= '0';` from the reset branch.